# Is it secure to have an iPad app run a webDAV server on localhost without authentication?

Tags: authentication, http, server, ios

I have two iPad apps running on the same device.

One is hosting a webDAV server on http://localhost:8080 without any authentication (the server is active whilst the app is foregrounded, and for a few minutes while it runs in the background). Does this mean that only other apps running on the same iPad will be able to access the server? Is this secure from outside attacks?

The second app reads and writes files from the webDAV server using GET, PUT, and PROPFIND.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly secure.

To intercept localhost traffic an attacker would need root privileges and at this point you've already lost as the attacker can also read and modify memory at will - no amount of cryptography will help you as the attacker will get your confidential data straight out of memory.

The only issue I see is that you can't prove it's indeed your app that you're talking to. What if another app suddenly starts a server on the same port ? To mitigate this you'd need to generate a key and a self-signed certificate on the first run of the app, and make whatever other browser/app that talks to that first app trust the cert. If some malicious app starts a server on the same port, it wouldn't be able to impersonate your real app.

Finally this seems like a crude way of doing IPC between apps - why not rely on what the OS already offers like App Groups - if you're the developer of both apps you can make them share the same group so they have some way of doing IPC as well as having shared storage :

> Use app groups to allow multiple apps access to shared containers and allow additional interprocess communication between apps. To enable app groups, in the Capabilities pane, click the switch in the App Groups section. You can select existing app groups from the table or add app groups.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I agree that it is a somewhat crude measure. I'm not the developer of either App, but one of them (Codea) is code-executing. I'm using it to read and write files from a webDAV. Hopefully Codea will get better iOS "share" integration in future and this sort of thing won't be needed (ironically, it used to be able to receive files via "Open In", but at some point in 2014, Apple required that all code-executing apps, Pythonista, Codea etc, remove this functionality, so that users have to resort to these kinds of workarounds. I have no idea why Apple would do such a thing)

Comment: I'm hoping you can expand a little on "To intercept localhost traffic an attacker would need root privileges". Why couldn't you find the IP of the iPad and access it from any other machine on the same subnet? e.g. 192.168.1.10:8080

Comment: @jeff-h yes you could, but that will only allow you to make a new connection, and not intercept traffic between two apps running on that iPad.

Comment: Ahh, of course! Thanks for clearing that up for me.